# What's the difference between `drawFunc` and `sceneFunc` in konvajs

Tags: konvajs

I checked the [Shape](https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Shape.html) and the [Line](https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Line.html). They both have `scensFunc`, but `Shape` has a `drawFunc` parameter in constructor.

Is there difference between `drawFunc` and `sceneFunc`? Why `Shape` has a draw function object in constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drawFunc` is deprecated and renamed to `sceneFunc`. So just use `sceneFunc`.